# Printf printing wrong char and 0

Tags: c++

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm new to C++. Why is it not copying all of the input to the output correctly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num1;
    long num2;
    long long num3;
    char char1;
    float num4;
    double num5;
    scanf("%d %ld %lld %c %f %lf", &num1, &num2, &num3, &char1, &num4, &num5);
    //input: 211916801 452082285 97592151379235457 p 19856.992 -5279235.721231465
    printf("%d %ld %lld %c %f %lf", num1, num2, &num3, &char1, &num4, &num5);
    //expected output: 211916801 452082285 97592151379235457 p 19856.992 -5279235.721231465
    //actual output: 211916801 452082285 68674564278975280 c 0.000000 0.000000
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `scanf()` and `printf()` in c++ code in 1st place?

Comment: because if I use cout it doesn't print the double with all the decimals, but with printf it does, also, that's what HackerRank asks me to do (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-basic-data-types?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

Comment: Check the `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision()` [manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Comment: Also please refrain to try learning, improving with these silly online code judge engines. Its just a complete waste of time, and won't make you fit for industry level programming at all (if not just the opposite).

Comment: Some people think the iostream libraries are poorly designed.

Answer (score 5):

Because you have `&` for some of the variables which is not what you intended.

```
printf("%d %ld %lld %c %f %lf", num1, num2, &num3, &char1, &num4, &num5);
```

should be

```
printf("%d %ld %lld %c %f %lf", num1, num2, num3, char1, num4, num5);
```

Your compiler should have warned about this as the values you pass don't match the format specifiers. If not, turn on/increase the compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4):

You should pass the values themselves, not pointers, to `printf`.

```
printf("%d %ld %lld %c %f %lf", num1, num2, num3, char1, num4, num5);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Printf(in most cases) you don't use & in your variables.

```
printf("%d %ld %lld %c %f %lf", num1, num2, num3, char1, num4, num5);
```

Plus, if you're new to C++, there's a better way to perform I/O Operations. Use "cin" instead of "scanf" and "cout" instead of "printf"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num1;
    long num2;
    long long num3;
    char char1;
    float num4;
    double num5;

   //scanf("%d %ld %lld %c %f %lf", &num1, &num2, &num3, &char1, &num4, &num5);
   cin >> num1;
   cin >> num2;
   cin >> num3;
   cin >> char1;
   cin >> num4;
   cin >> num5;
   //input: 211916801 452082285 97592151379235457 p 19856.992 -5279235.721231465

   //printf("%d %ld %lld %c %f %lf", num1, num2, &num3, &char1, &num4, &num5);
   cout << num1;
   cout << num2;
   cout << num3;
   cout << char1;
   cout << num4;
   cout << num5;

   //expected output: 211916801 452082285 97592151379235457 p 19856.992 -5279235.721231465
   //actual output: 211916801 452082285 68674564278975280 c 0.000000 0.000000

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using your code the output is incorrect for the double, it is supposed to be -5279235.721231465, but it prints out as -5279235.721231. Using printf instead of cout solves this.

Comment: @kirill2485: That's not "incorrect". If you care about a specific amount of precision then you need to state that with _either_ approach. You're just getting lucky that `printf` happens to default to what you want. Switching IO libraries because of this (instead of researching how to configure your tool) is ludicrous! You should have better reasons for such choices.

Answer (score 0):

While using `printf(...)`, primitive types are passed by value not by reference. Use below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num1;
    long num2;
    long long num3;
    char char1;
    float num4;
    double num5;
    scanf("%d %ld %lld %c %f %lf", &num1, &num2, &num3, &char1, &num4, &num5);
    printf("%d %ld %lld %c %f %lf", num1, num2, num3, char1, num4, num5);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```